# Spark streaming creates empty creates empty batches after restarting from the checkpoint

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

[Spark Streaming UI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEAHU.png)

I use Spark 2.1 (pyspark), Amazon Kinesis stream.
When I restart application from the checkpoint it creates empty batches for whole time while my application was down. 
Also I see next error during each empty batch processing:

```
com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.ProvisionedThroughputExceededException: 
Rate exceeded for shard shardId-000000000028 in stream 
StreamEvents under account 567616515857. 
(Service: AmazonKinesis; Status Code: 400; 
Error Code: ProvisionedThroughputExceededException; 
Request ID: d56404a8-ecc2-2093-8449-221a1db9543c)
```

with different shard IDs.

Is it possible to disable creating empty batches after restarting from checkpoint?